# Scroll bar of select drop down chopped off in IE9

Tags: html, cross-browser

Remember how IE8 use to limit the size(width specifically) of select drop down when there was explicit width styled to the `<select>` tag. It seemed that IE9 fixed that but wait, select is not yet perfect in IE...

Chrome and firefox elegantly place its select **drop down** depending upon the space available around the **select**. See this example in chrome, firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/hnQUL/2/

which basically is this.

```
<div style='float:left; width:100%; text-align:right;'>
<select style='width:200px;'>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
.
.
.
.

    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**BUT** IE9 refuses and the scroll bar of drop down gets chopped off.

Any idea?

Problem reproduced as below

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my end. IE9/Win7

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall Question accompanied by an image. Vertical scroll lost into oblivion.

Comment: Win7/IE9, not able to reproduce. IE9 repositioned the select based on browser width and scroll bar was visible at all times.